# Formula for the large derivative

Tags: derivatives

Is there any formula for the large number derivative?
I need to find $y^{(100)}$ at $x=0$, if $y=(x+1)2^{x+1}$

I tried to find a pattern, but 2nd and 3rd derivatives are already too hairy. I see no pattern, how it evolves.

1st derivative $2^{x+1}+\ln \left(2\right)\cdot \:2^{x+1}\left(x+1\right)$
or $2^{x+1}(1+ln(2)(x+1))$

2nd $\ln ^2\left(2\right)\cdot \:2^{x+1}x+\ln ^2\left(2\right)\cdot \:2^{x+1}+\ln \left(2\right)\cdot \:2^{x+2}$

3rd $\ln ^2\left(2\right)\left(\ln \left(2\right)\cdot \:2^{x+1}x+2^{x+1}\right)+\ln ^3\left(2\right)\cdot \:2^{x+1}+\ln ^2\left(2\right)\cdot \:2^{x+2}$

Comment: You should state the 2nd and 3rd derivatives here if you've found them. Saves us some work, and shows your effort (even though you've said you've done them, the whole effort thing seems to be sacred on this website)

Comment: Hint: think about Taylor / MacLaurin series.

Comment: Use the general Leibniz rule

Comment: Have you tried logarithmic differentiation?

Comment: maybe substitute variables $t=x+1$ and find derivative at $t=-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=x+1$ and $v=2^{x+1}$.

$u^{(1)}=1$, $u^{(k)}=0$ for $k\ge 2$.

$v^{(k)}=2^{x+1}(\ln2)^k$ for $k\ge 1$.

By the general Leibniz rule, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)

$$y^{(100)}=uv^{(100)}+\binom{100}{1}u^{(1)}v^{(99)}=(x+1)2^{x+1}(\ln 2)^{100}+100\cdot2^{x+1}(\ln 2)^{99}$$

$$y^{(100)}(0)=2(\ln 2)^{100}+200(\ln 2)^{99}$$

Answer (score 0):

I see all kinds of fancy techniques in the comments, no need for that. There's a pretty simple pattern here.

First define $g(x)=2^{x+1}$ and $f(x)=x2^{x+1}=xg(x)$. Now $y=f+g$, so to find $y^{(100)}$, we have to find $f^{(100)}$ and $g^{(100)}$.

For $g$, this isn't too hard; $g^{(n)}(x)=\log(2)^n2^{x+1}$, and you can prove this by induction easily.

For $f(x)$, we see $f'(x)=g(x)+xg'(x)$, and $f^{(2)}(x)=g'(x)+g'(x)+xg^{(2)}(x)$. From this, it's easy enough to see a pattern; $f^{(n)}(x)=ng^{(n-1)}(x)+xg^{(n)}(x)$. This too is easy enough to prove with induction.

In the end,

\begin{align}
y^{(100)}(x)&=f^{(100)}(x)+g^{(100)}(x)\\
&=100g^{(99)}(x)+xg^{(100)}(x)+g^{(100)}(x)\\
&=100\log(2)^{99}2^{x+1}+x\log(2)^{100}2^{x+1}+\log(2)^{100}2^{x+1}\\
\end{align}

Now at $x=0$, we get
$$200\log(2)^{99}+2\log(2)^{100}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use Taylor series:
$$y=2(x+1)\left(1+x\ln 2+\frac{x^2}{2!}\ln^2 2+\cdots \right)=\\
[2x+\cdots +\frac{2x^{100}}{99!}\ln^{99} 2+O(x^{101})]+\\
[2+\cdots+\frac{2x^{100}}{100!}\ln^{100} 2+O(x^{101})].$$
$$y^{(100)}(0)=200\ln^{99} 2+2\ln^{100} 2.$$